# How can i count the numbers that given in bulk on python

Tags: python, count

So I have these lines in python

```
l=list("09073146864462346440228042814284764104460294046232864221188427140442613004261248")

print("There is ",l.count("1"+"2"+"3"+"4"+"5"+"6"+"7"+"8"+"9"+"0")," Numbers in it")
```

I want it to count as separate the output would be like there is 50 numbers here.

Comment: what you want exactly? to count how many times occur '1','2' etc? or what

Comment: Are you trying to count the occurrence?

Comment: Are you looking for [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)?

Comment: im trying to find how many numbers in the list that given

Comment: Surely you mean the length of the list?

Comment: len(l) will do then..

Comment: len() is the answer thanks a lot i dont know how i forgot it, havent been coding for a while

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: No len() was enough

Answer (score 0):

So im told it was len() function so it is solved thanks*
the code should be

```
l=list("09073146864462346440228042814284764104460294046232864221188427140442613004261248")

print("There is ",len(l)," Numbers in it")
```